# How To get labels for each geom line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to get a label for each of the geom lines that I have in the below code , and have tried adding `scale_color_manual(values = c("Cases", "Deaths"))`  but it does nothing.

I know one solution would be to split the cases and death columns into seperate rows and add a type column to identify if the row is death or case type , but I'd like to avoid duplicating the number of rows x 2 .

The this is the result of head(filtered) for data structure  reference

```
filtered <- structure(list(dt = structure(c(18505, 18504, 18503, 18502, 18501, 
                                            18500), class = "Date"), cases = c(40L, 141L, 126L, 90L, 162L, 
                                                                               85L), deaths = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), country = c("Ireland", 
                                                                                                                                     "Ireland", "Ireland", "Ireland", "Ireland", "Ireland")), row.names = c(NA,
```

```
 ggplot(filtered) + 
  geom_line( aes(x=dt, y= cases  ) , size=1  , color="#00AFBB"  ) +   #Label Should be "Cases"
  geom_line( aes(x=dt, y= deaths  ) , size=1  , color="#FC4E07" ) +   #Label should be "Deaths" 
  facet_grid(~ country) + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = '7 days') +
 
  labs(title = "Ireland & UK ",
       subtitle = "March 01 - 31 August ",
       y = "Cases / Deaths",   x = "Date") +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2")+
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1) , axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 40, hjust = 1))
```

Current Output , Red square is where the Legend should be

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a legend you have to map on the `color` aes. To achive your desired result without `pivot_longer` map e.g. "cases" and "deaths" on `color` and make use of `scale_color_manual` to set the colors like so:

```
filtered <- structure(list(dt = structure(c(18505, 18504, 18503, 18502, 18501, 
                                            18500), class = "Date"), cases = c(40L, 141L, 126L, 90L, 162L, 
                                                                               85L), deaths = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), country = c("Ireland", 
                                                                                                                                     "Ireland", "Ireland", "Ireland", "Ireland", "Ireland")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                            -6L), class = "data.frame")
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(filtered) + 
  geom_line( aes(x=dt, y= cases, color="cases"    ) , size=1  ) +   #Label Should be "Cases"
  geom_line( aes(x=dt, y= deaths, color="deaths"  ) , size=1  ) +   #Label should be "Deaths" 
  facet_grid(~ country) + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = '7 days') +
  
  labs(title = "Ireland & UK ",
       subtitle = "March 01 - 31 August ",
       y = "Cases / Deaths",   x = "Date") +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(cases = "#00AFBB", deaths = "#FC4E07"),
                     labels = c(cases = "Cases", deaths = "Deaths")) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1) , axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 40, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although is mentioned that rows should not be duplicated, you can create the reshaped data in long format easily using `pivot_longer()`:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -c(dt,country)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=dt,y=value,group=name,color=name))+
  geom_line()+
  facet_grid(~ country) + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = '1 days') +
  labs(title = "Ireland & UK ",
       subtitle = "March 01 - 31 August ",
       y = "Cases / Deaths",   x = "Date") +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1) ,
        axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 40, hjust = 1))
```

Output:

[image]